# Can't send any mail using JavaMail

Tags: java, email

I want to send a mail using Java but it doesn't work using this tutorial thai I found here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm .

Here is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("smtp.laposte.net", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

And I have the error below:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at javamail.JavaMail.main(JavaMail.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 7 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: then find another example on the net that works?

Comment: Try what Tipu Sultan suggested below. If that doesn't work then find another example on the net that works :P

Comment: also, you do know that in your program you have to put correct gmail userID and correct password?

Answer (score 1):

error is in host use

```
host="smtp.gmail.com";
```

if you are using gmail id for sending mail. then you need to turn on gmail sending mail from extrnel application for users.
follow below link https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919?hl=en 
turn on and then try again.

Comment: just try what you have ask. please don't comment like this.

Comment: I don't have any "Google for Work" account. But chen i change the ISP server it does the same. Can my ISP block my 25 port ? I am on Orange in France

Comment: @JohnMary what do you want to ask ?

Comment: I have not any "google for Work" account mentionned here https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919?hl=en . So, I tried to change my SMTP server, but it does exactly the same error. So, is it possible that my ISP block my 25 port to send any mail from my box ?

Comment: In fact, I can't turn on gmail sending mail from extrnel application for users because I don't have any "google for work" account

Comment: there are some permission in mail server for using id but sending mails from another application using server and port. may be i that server you don't have permission to send emai from external application

Answer (score 1):

you can also use spring for sending mail.

bean.xml

```
<bean id="myMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="<user_name>" />
        <property name="password" value="<password>" />

        <!-- The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions -->
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

.

```
@Service("myMail")
    public class myMailApi {

        @Autowired
        private MailSender myMailSender;

        public void sendMail(String to,String from,String subject, String body){
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMailMessage.setTo(to);
            simpleMailMessage.setFrom(from);
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);
            simpleMailMessage.setText(body);
            myMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
        }
    }



private static void sendMailClient() {
        String mailXml = "mail-bean.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(mailXml);
        myMailApi mailBean = (mmyMailApi) context
                .getBean("myMail");
        mailBean.sendMail("<to>",
                "<from>", "<subject>", "<body>");
    }
```

Comment: ignore it. have you got you answer. is it solved? let me know if not

Comment: Tipu Sultan I am not the questioner of this question. John Mary is.

Answer (score 0):

With which server I can send email without have an account and login in java mail api ?
Is hotmail autorizing sending emails without logging in in java mail ?